# Optimizing sqlite insert queries

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database (using SQLite in C#) with a table to store sentences, a table to store each individual word that is used in those sentences, and a junction table that relates the words to the sentences that they appear in.
I am then trying to populate the database with over 15 million sentences. I estimate that there are about 150 million inserts happening in my code.
Right now, my code is only doing a couple hundred sentences per second, which will take forever to get through this huge data set. How can I make this faster?

I tried putting the ENTIRE thing in a single transaction, but I'm not sure if that can work due to the huge amount of data. So I am using one transaction for each sentence.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE sentences ( sid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, sentence TEXT ); 
CREATE TABLE words ( wid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, dictform TEXT UNIQUE); 
CREATE TABLE sentence_words( sid INTEGER NOT NULL, wid INTEGER NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_sentence_words PRIMARY KEY ( sid, wid ), FOREIGN KEY(sid) REFERENCES Sentences(sid), FOREIGN KEY(wid) REFERENCES Words(wid));
```

Code:

```
while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null) //read in a new sentence
        {
            tr = m_dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
            sql = "INSERT INTO sentences (sentence) VALUES(@sentence)";
            cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sentence", input);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            dict_words = jutils.onlyDict(input); //convert all words to their 'dictionary form'
            var words = dict_words.Split(' ');
            foreach (var wd in words) //for each word
            {
                sql = "INSERT or IGNORE INTO words (dictform) VALUES(@dictform)";
                cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dictform", wd);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                sql = "INSERT or IGNORE INTO sentence_words (sid, wid) VALUES((SELECT sid FROM sentences WHERE sentence = @sentence), (SELECT wid FROM words WHERE dictform = @dictform))";
                cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sentence", input);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dictform", wd);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Always, we must avoid the 'one by one' SQL tasks when dealing with such large data.

In my case, (if memory is not burdened), load the data into a DataTable and manipulate(with LINQ) as you need, and finally use SqlBulkCopy at the end.

There's SqlBulkUpdate also but created by private author supporting from SQL 2008.
If under 2008, we can still quickly do this but have to create temporary SQL table and use UPDATE Join command.

SqlBulkCopy is really fast like just seconds.

Comment: After some testing of the queries for each of my tables, is seems like the really slow part is my junction table. In order to do each insert in this table, I'm having to do selects across another huge table, which seems to be the problem.  I'm not really familiar with data tables or linq, but I'm assuming that in order to create the data for the junction table, I would still have to do the same type of operations, no?  Any ideas on how I would simplify this aspect of it?

Comment: My case was only 10~ 30 thousands rows but I gave up. You'd better to know it's 'times x numbers of rows' regardless of how small word with 1 column. Iterating millions times of SQL physical connection will take forever..If you have to deal with SQL database, you'd better to be familiarized with DataTable, LINQ, Subquery, BulkCopy, BulkUpdate, LINQtoSQL.Iterating millions times 'one by one' would be nightmare..

Comment: Learning takes only few days but the perfomance will be really satisfying.

Comment: foreach is really superfast as you know but if SQL is inside, it's no more superfast. It would be most critical to reduce the numbers of candidates rows and to change inserting technology. And if the sentences and words table are a kind of fixed dictionary. They will stay always same. Load them into DataTable in order to utilize the fastest speed of RAM memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by a certain number of lines

```
int lines = -1; 
int group = 500;
while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
     lines++;
     if (lines%group == 0) {
        tr = m_dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
        }
```

and commit each group

```
     if (lines%group == group-1) {
        tr.Commit();
        }
    }
if (lines%group >= 0 && lines%group <  group-1) {
    tr.Commit();
    }
```

I had some old cases where I was forced to use .Net 4.0 and BulkCopy was not an option due to its async implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the entire thing in a single transaction. (The rollback journal stores the old version of any page changed by the transaction, so for an empty database, it cannot become big.)

Furthermore, all the searches for the `sentence` value are inefficient because the database has to go through the entire table. If that column had an index (explicitly, or implicitly with a UNIQUE constraint), these lookups would be much faster.

Comment: Seems like this might be correct. I had originally tested it within visual studio debug mode, and I was watching my memory usage slowly increase as the program ran. But after compiling it and letting it run for several hours, my memory actually has not increased at all.

However, the code seems to be getting slower and slower as it goes. After running for several hours, it has only managed to complete a little over 200,000 sentences out of 15 million. So even with it all wrapped in a single transaction, its much too slow.

Comment: It's probably all those unindexed lookups of `sentence`.